# Запятая перед что-то

Tags: пунктуация

"В ее дневнике было написано() что-то вроде..." Нужна ли запятая на месте пропуска?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна.

Comment: Извините, а Вы не могли бы сказать почему именно она здесь не ставится?

Comment: См.ответ Александра.

Comment: Появилась новая привилегия? Распасовщик указывает на какой Ответ глаза скосить. Строку, если не затруднит!

Comment: Вы о чем? Порой вас бывает трудно понять.

Comment: Ответ вышел не развернутым. Далее следует кивок на ответ другого человека. Вопрос: что есть такого в не аргументированной фразе, если рядом — аргументированный текст? А вот что: в ней — полезная ссылка на другой ответ.

Comment: Ну знаете. Я ответил, а после меня Александр.  Чтобы не повторяться, я сослался на его ответ. Каждый пусть следит за своими ответом.

Answer (score 3):

Ни в коем случае. Для наглядности: с запятой это выглядело бы примерно как "Мама мыла, раму". Здесь сразу за сказуемым прямое дополнение. А вот в случае "В дневнике была сделана запись, что-то вроде замечания..." запятая была бы нужна - перед уточнением.